# webpack - require('node_modules/leaflet/leaflet.css')

Tags: css, node.js, npm, leaflet, webpack

So I'm trying to build a map app using `webpack` and `leaflet`. I can require `leaflet.js` from my `map.js` file, but I can't call leaflet.css without getting an error.

My current `webpack.config.js` looks like:

```
'use strict'

var webpack = require('webpack'),
    path = require('path'),
    HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'),
    srcPath = path.join(__dirname, 'src');

module.exports = {
    target: "web",
    cache: true,
    entry: {
        app: path.join(srcPath, "index.js")
    },
    resolve: {
        alais: {
            leaflet_css: __dirname + "/node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"
        }
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
          {test: /\.js?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader"},
          {test: /\.scss?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "style!css!sass!"},
          {test: /\.css?$/, loader: "style!css!"}
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin("common", "common.js"),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          inject: true,
          template: "src/index.html"
        }),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
      ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        publicPath: "/dist/",
        filename: "[name].js",
        pathInfo: true
    }
}
```

And my `main.js` file looks like:

```
var $ = require('jquery'),
    leaflet = require('leaflet');

require("./sass/main.scss");
require("leaflet_css");

var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
    .openPopup();

console.log('I got called');
```

What is the correct approach of bundling css files from 3rd party suppliers via webpack?

I saw [this project](https://github.com/Summer-Top/single-page-react-webpack) were `leaflet` is stored in the libs directory... what's the reason for this, why store it in the `libs` directory if it is installed into the `node_modules` direcory via `npm`?

This is very much a learning exercise so any pointers are greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Example of how to load static CSS files from node\_modules using webpack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34311656/example-of-how-to-load-static-css-files-from-node-modules-using-webpack)

Comment: @Drew - This question was posted earlier - your example is a duplicate. Unfortunately I don't have sufficient access to make it as such.

Answer (score 14):

So it turns out, the answer is a combination of webpack's resolve.alias and the file loader. My new webpack file looks like this:

```
'use strict'

var webpack = require('webpack'),
    path = require('path'),
    HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'),
    srcPath = path.join(__dirname, 'src');

module.exports = {
    target: "web",
    cache: true,
    entry: {
        app: path.join(srcPath, "index.js")
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.html', '.js', '.json', '.scss', '.css'],
        alias: {
            leaflet_css: __dirname + "/node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css",
            leaflet_marker: __dirname + "/node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png",
            leaflet_marker_2x: __dirname + "/node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png",
            leaflet_marker_shadow: __dirname + "/node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png"
        }
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
          {test: /\.js?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader"},
          {test: /\.scss?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!"},
          {test: /\.css?$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader!"},
          {test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: "file-loader?name=images/[name].[ext]"}
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin("common", "common.js"),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          inject: true,
          template: "src/index.html"
        }),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
      ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        publicPath: "/dist/",
        filename: "[name].js",
        pathInfo: true
    }
}
```

And then all I need to do is require the icons in the .js file

```
require("./sass/main");
require("leaflet_css");
require("leaflet_marker");
require("leaflet_marker_2x");
require("leaflet_marker_shadow");
```

Lovely!!! :)

Comment: This threat might be of help too https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/255

Comment: Without the aliases you can also `require("leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png")` etc.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it easier. Just needed to add loaders for css and for png

```
loaders: [
    { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
    {
        test: /\.png$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        query: { mimetype: 'image/png' }
    }
]
```