# Example of how to load static CSS files from node_modules using webpack?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I don't know how to load with webpack any CSS from node_modules libs, for example I've installed leaflet and each attempt of load `leaflet/dist/leaflet.css` fails.

Could you provide example how to load static styles from node_modules?

My current webpack config below. Additionaly I'm using `extract-text-webpack-plugin` and `sass-loader` my project scss files are working well, I have also `css-loader`, have I to resolve static css files or add something to `stylePathResolves`?

```
//require('leaflet/dist/leaflet.css');

var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require('path');

var stylePathResolves = (
  'includePaths[]=' + path.resolve('./') + '&' +
  'includePaths[]=' + path.resolve('./node_modules')
)

module.exports = {
  entry: ".js/app.js",
  output: {
    path: "./static/js",
    filename: "app.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel'
      }, {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
          'style',
          'css' + '!sass?outputStyle=expanded&' + stylePathResolves
        )
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new ExtractTextPlugin("app.css")]
};
```

Where to load leaflet.css, commented out `require('leaflet/dist/leaflet.css')` gives me following error:

```
home/myproj/node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css:3
.leaflet-map-pane,
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For users who have encountered a similar problem, there are steps that I've done to get it working, I'm not sure that this equilibrium way.

1. `npm install file-loader --save`
2. add `import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';` in main app.js
3. change webpack.config.js by following way:

add `css-loader` to get rid of `SyntaxError: Unexpected token .` and next add `file-loader` and match files to get rid of `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./images/layers.png"`:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./web/static/js/app.js",
  output: {
    path: "./priv/static/js",
    filename: "app.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel'
    }, {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
        'style',
        'css' + '!sass?outputStyle=expanded&' + stylePathResolves
      )
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
    }, {
      test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$/,
      loader: 'file-loader'
    }]
  },
  plugins: [new ExtractTextPlugin("app.css")]
};
```

At the beginning I got this config from some example and it's not 100% clear why I've used `ExtractTextPlugin` to load scss and what the correlation is with css-loader, maybe to be more coherent should I use ExtractTextPlugin also in this part, maybe someone knows and can code review? But my solution is working and I can work further.

Comment: Thanks @luzny! You can accept your own answer if you like ;)

Comment: I have been struggling with this issue for a couple of days and though I will never be able to import my bootstrap.css file.
After adding the images and fonts test rule it removed the errors I had.
What I'm trying to say is you saved me bro!

Comment: If god were one of us his name would be 'Iuzny' - this is nothing more than the truth. I have been trying this out for days and ages. May the gods be with you, i wish you will be healthy your lifetime long bro!

Answer (score 4):

I had to do:

```
npm install --save-dev style-loader css-loader file-loader
```

If I didn't configure the file loader for the images, I got:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/layers-2x.png 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css) 7:8888-8921
 @ ./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css
 @ ./src/view/component/RouteMap.js
 @ ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/layers.png 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css) 7:8716-8746
 @ ./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css
 @ ./src/view/component/RouteMap.js
 @ ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css) 7:9975-10010
 @ ./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css
 @ ./src/view/component/RouteMap.js
 @ ./src/index.js
```

***You also MUST import the CSS file in your `index.js` or `main.js` (or whatever your main JS file is called). Otherwise, you get an error saying that `module.exports is read-only`.***

```
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
```

A more updated `webpack.config.js` snippet is:

```
{
    ...
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.css$/, use: ["style-loader","css-loader"] },
            { test: /\.(png|svg|jpe?g|gif|woff2?|ttf|eot)$/, use: [ 'file-loader' ] },
        ],
    },
```

Comment: This is better solution. Loaders should be added dev only, and it uses new format of config.