# PrimeNG stylesheets not found

Tags: angular, webpack, stylesheet, node-modules, primeng

I'm having trouble with a new project I've just created. For some reason when trying to import the stylesheets of PrimeNG I'm getting a 404 error. I don't know if it's something to do with the configuration of my project.

I'm using the Angular Class WebPack Starter, I've added PrimeNG but as mentioned above I'm getting a 404 error. Although it doesn't make much sense I'm suspecting that it's related to the fact that the stylesheets are in the `node_modules` folder. As a test I've put a `.css` file in the `node_modules` folder and it wasn't found. However, when put in my "global" folder for the public assets the file was found.

**Screenshot with the test stylesheet and the PrimeNG theme**

[image]

**Screenshot with the test stylesheet moved to `public` folder and the PrimeNG theme**

[image]

I know it's a trivial issue but I can't seem to find any information. Just in case I've also looked at [PrimeNG's setup](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup) page however it did not make a difference.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same with  problem with a Angular2 app and managed to get around it by importing the .css files directly into the my main.ts script.

This post helped me : [Example of how to load static CSS files from node_modules using webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34311656/example-of-how-to-load-static-css-files-from-node-modules-using-webpack)

I just followed the instruction in the post mentioned above and added this to my main.ts.

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import 'primeng/resources/themes/afterdark/theme.css';
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
import 'primeng/resources/primeng.min.css';

import { AppModule } from './modules/app.module';
const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue related to missing css files, If you are using angular-cli to build your project, follow these steps :

1-Edit your project's angular-cli.json file

2-Update Styles section by adding needed css files as follows:

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css", // default generated one
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css" , //primeng css
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.css" //primeng css
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the "styles" array includes the prime ng style sheets under the "build" AND "test" (under "architect" under the project under "projects"):

```
"styles": [
  "./node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
  "./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
  "./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
],
```

Other stylesheets will probably already be there. Other themes are available.