# Vue-cli import assets css relative not working

Tags: css, webpack, sass, vue-cli

i'm using vue-cli + this webpack template for my vue project, i wanted to use leaflet in my website but when i import their css file, i have the following errors :

**code for import**

```
<style lang="scss">
    @import "../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
</style>



These relative modules were not found:

* ./images/layers-2x.png in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-7ba5bd90",
"scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles
&index=0&bustCache!./src/App.vue
* ./images/layers.png in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-7ba5bd90","sc
oped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&in
dex=0&bustCache!./src/App.vue
* ./images/marker-icon.png in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-7ba5bd90","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0&bustCache!./src/App.vue
```

and the problem is that webpack consider the image path relative to my project root src folder, i tried to copy and past the images folder in `leaflet/dist/images` to my project src folder, and its worked. so how can i make this work?

Comment: you can check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34311656/example-of-how-to-load-static-css-files-from-node-modules-using-webpack

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is simply the lang with sccs not corresponding with leaflet.css ?

```
<style lang="css">
    @import "../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
</style>
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have quite the same problem : Vue-cli import assets css relative not working  for vendors **external** librairies **in style files** :

If I take this versions of vue and @vue-cli :

> packadge.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.0.0-beta.15",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.0.0-beta.15",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.0-beta.15",
    "buefy": "^0.6.6",
    "bulma": "^0.7.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.16"
  },
```

I have no any problems with relative links **inside** my application, but if I import **externals** like buefy or bulma, in a style file, I have the same problem.

**Basic Reproduction :**

- Install  @vue-cli @*(npm remove vue-cli; npm remove -g vue-cli; npm install -g @vue/cli)*
- I create a basic project  *(vue create relative-css-demo)*
- Install bulma & buefy  *(npm install bulma buefy)*
- I create a basic color asset with bulma import :

> src/assets/vars/colors.scss

```
@import "../../../node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/_all";
```

- Set App style in a separate scss file :

> src/App.vue

```
<style lang="scss" src="./App.scss"></style>
```

> src/App.scss

```
@import './assets/vars/colors.scss'
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

**And you have the bug :**

> ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors
>
> error  in ./src/App.scss?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss
>
> Module build failed (from
>   /home/awa/Projets/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
>
> @import "../../../node_modules/bulma"; ^
>         File to import not found or unreadable: ../../../node_modules/bulma. Parent style sheet:
>   /home/awa/Projets/vues-templates/simple-relative-css-demo/src/assets/vars/colors.scss
>         in /home/awa/Projets/vues-templates/simple-relative-css-demo/src/assets/vars/colors.scss
>   (line 75, column 1)
>
> @
>   ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--8-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!/home/awa/Projets/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!./src/App.scss?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss
>   4:14-310 14:3-18:5 14:310-18:4 15:22-318  @
>   ./src/App.scss?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss  @ ./src/App.vue  @
>   ./src/main.js  @ multi
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080/sockjs-node
>   (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

But if I import colors inside style tag it works. 
Even if I import another asset scss files of my own in App.scss it is ok ...

> src/App.vue

```
<style lang="scss" src="./App.scss">
  @import './assets/vars/colors.scss'
</style>
```

> src/App.scss

```
@import './assets/vars/noexternals.scss'
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

> DONE  Compiled successfully in 268ms