# Do I have to import leaflet's CSS file?

Tags: node.js, leaflet, webpack

I'm using Node / React / Webpack with leaflet. I installed leaflet using npm and in my map component I import 'leaflet'; which works fine for the js.

However, the map does not look correct due to the css not working correctly, however images stored in the leaflet/dist/images seem to work fine. In order to get the css to work I have to also import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css' but it feels to me like I shouldn't have to and that it should be included with the first import statement?

Comment: Yes you have to have, see this link might be useful: [leaflet-css webpack require](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732066/webpack-requirenode-modules-leaflet-leaflet-css)

Comment: When I miss the CSS, I get a crazy tiled set that is all in the wrong order and draggable in a weird way; if you seem to end up with that then you are missing the CSS. So yep def need it:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Example of how to load static CSS files from node\_modules using webpack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34311656/example-of-how-to-load-static-css-files-from-node-modules-using-webpack)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have to have, see this link might be useful:

[leaflet-css webpack require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732066/webpack-requirenode-modules-leaflet-leaflet-css)

I omitted its CSS in an `ionic` project but copied a few necessary lines to avoid a broken map UI.

Comment: In that example they also have to import all the images, however those get picked up. Any idea why the images do but not the css?

Comment: ah! infact that is not making any technicaly sense :) sort of confusion sounds try but better approach is include even minimal