# How to set marker icon in leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

I have my component MAP and I use leaflet (not react-leaflet).
I want to set a marker.

This is the code of my component.

```
import React from 'react';
import L from 'leaflet';
import '../../../../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import './map.scss';



export default class Map extends React.Component {


  componentDidMount() {

    this.map = L.map('map', {
      center: [48.8762, 2.357909999999947],
      zoom: 14,
      zoomControl: true,
      layers: [
        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.de/tiles/osmde/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{
          detectRetina: true,
          maxZoom: 20,
          maxNativeZoom: 17,
        }),
      ]
    });

    L.marker([48.8762, 2.357909999999947],
      {
        draggable: true,        // Make the icon dragable
        title: 'Hover Text',     // Add a title
        opacity: 0.5}            // Adjust the opacity
    )
      .addTo(this.map)
      .bindPopup("<b>Paris</b><br>Gare de l'Est")
      .openPopup();

    L.circle([48.8762, 2.357909999999947], {
      color: 'red',
      fillColor: '#f03',
      fillOpacity: 0.5,
      radius: 500
    }).addTo(this.map);

  };


  render() {
    return <div className="map" id="map" />
  }
}
```

I add the marker us described in the documentation, but the result in the map is not the default icon, it is only a square with a thin border. 
I checked the css-File from leaflet. The icon is in the images folder, but it is not in the map available.

This icon (marker) I am looking for
[image]

This is what I get
[image]

Can anybody help or see what is wrong with my code?

Comment: can you paste screenshots of desired and actual?

Comment: in place of `import '../../../../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';` try writing `import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I have to import leaflet's CSS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796851/do-i-have-to-import-leaflets-css-file)

Comment: @iamsaksham no, it is not a duplicate

Comment: can you see the icon png files in the network tab (developer's console) being requested?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a well known css bundle issue with webpack. Define markerIcon as

```
const markerIcon = L.icon({
  iconSize: [25, 41],
  iconAnchor: [10, 41],
  popupAnchor: [2, -40],
  // specify the path here
  iconUrl: "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/images/marker-icon.png",
  shadowUrl: "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/images/marker-shadow.png"
});
```

and assign it to the icon property of `L.marker` like this:

```
 L.marker(
      [48.8762, 2.357909999999947],
      {
        draggable: true, // Make the icon dragable
        title: "Hover Text", // Add a title
        opacity: 0.5,
        icon: markerIcon // here assign the markerIcon var
      } // Adjust the opacity
    )
      .addTo(this.map)
      .bindPopup("<b>Paris</b><br>Gare de l'Est")
      .openPopup();
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-set-marker-icon-in-leaflet-map-p878y)

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, I can interpret that you are not able to import the CSS properly.

You can import the css for the leaflet module by writing

`import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';`

For detailed explanation you can read

[Do I have to import leaflet's CSS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796851/do-i-have-to-import-leaflets-css-file)

[Example of how to load static CSS files from node_modules using webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34311656/example-of-how-to-load-static-css-files-from-node-modules-using-webpack)